OMV cm3588 nvme not detected
I got a cm3588 and kit, with 12V 4A supply, set it up, but only 3 of 4 ssd were detected. I use 4 crucial p3 nvme pcie 3.0.
I tried to interchange the ssds but seems like port 4 is not working. All ssds that I put there don't work, but would work on the other ports. So the ssds are not a problem. Also, from that 4 leds (one for each port), just the first 3 are flashing.

If it's broken, return/replace it. Simple as that.
